# Password submitted in form does not match password at the database

Tags: php, authentication, pdo, md5

I wrote a login form, and after hitting the submit button, I want to check if the user exists at the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
    if($_POST['senderLogin'] == 'customer'){
        $checkIfExists = new CustomersDAO();
        $stam = $checkIfExists->isExist($_POST["name"], $_POST["password"]);
        var_dump($stam);
    }
}
```

And the checking I do like that:

```
public function isExist($name, $password) {
    $this->connect();
    if($this->con){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name=? AND password=?";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $password = md5($password);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $fetched = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        $this->disconnect();
        if($fetched > 0) {
            return true;
        } else { 
            return FALSE;}
    }
}
```

The passwords at the database are encrypted with md5.

I tried to type a user that exists at the customers table, and it didn't work.

I tried to match only the names and it worked, so the problem is with the comparison of the password submitted with the passwords at the database.

Comment: OT but MD5 is not encryption and it is not a recommend method for hashing passwords.

Comment: have you checked if you are getting correct password in `$_POST["password"]`?

Comment: MD5 [is insufficient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

Comment: To give you a start to debug this and help you solve any future problems, try echoing out your query. make sure that what it is looking for is what you think it is and see if it matches what is in the database. Normally the problem is that people forgot to hash the password when they stored it in the DB, Better yet though throw this out and use a pre-made authentication library as there are so many pitfalls for the unwary it does not make sense to roll your own unless you have highly custom requirements

Comment: Are you sure the length for the column is long enough for your md5 encrypted pass? I once had the length on 25 which sometimes was too short and I would get the same problem as you are facing right now.

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Write this as an answer so I can accept it(if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code, and...

> "I tried to match only the names and it worked, so the problem is with the comparison of the password submitted with the passwords at the database."

When using hash functions with passwords or sensitive data, developers generally append "salt" strings to it to help prevent easy break of these hashs. I see that in your code you just use `md5()` on the password without any kind of salt. And maybe on the other point of the script, in the function that adds user to the database for example, you are hashing the password with some salt and obviously the hash won't match.

Comment: This seems to be a comment more than an answer.

Answer (score -3):

you need to encrypt your password with md5

```
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
    if($_POST['senderLogin'] == 'customer'){
        $checkIfExists = new CustomersDAO();
        $stam = $checkIfExists->isExist($_POST["name"], md5($_POST["password"]) );
        var_dump($stam);
    }
}
```

Comment: One does not simply "encrypt" anything with md5() Also he is already doing that when he binds his params

Comment: I did at the isExist function